# giving a type signature to `_` in haskell

Tags: haskell

I want to associate `_` with `coerce` yet I can't give a type signature to it.

Is there any trickery to get around that ?

```hs
import Data.Coerce

ok :: ()
ok =
  let a = _ "hi"
   in let a :: String = __ "Hi"
       in ()
  where
    _ = undefined
    __ :: Coercible a b => a -> b
    __ = coerce

ko =
  let a = _ "hi"
   in let a :: String = __ "Hi"
       in ()
  where
    __ = undefined
    _ :: Coercible a b => a -> b. -- Invalid type signature: _ :: ... Should be of form <variable> :: <type>parser
    _ = coerce
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`_` is a reserved name which can not be redefined. It can be used in patterns as a wildcard, e.g.

```
let (_,x) = ....           -- takes the second component
    (_,_,_,x,_) = ....     -- takes the fourth component
    _ = ....               -- does not bind any variable
in ....
```

Unlike other variable names, it can appear more than once in a pattern.

It can also be used as a *hole*: e.g.,

```
let a = _ "hi"
```

triggers the special error

```
• Found hole: _ :: [Char] -> t
  Where: ‘t’ is a rigid type variable bound by
           the inferred type of a :: t
```

Essentially, `_ "hi"` asks the compiler to provide which type a term `t` should have to make the whole expression type-check when hole `_` is replaced by `t`.

Therefore, your `ok` esample is not really OK, but triggers the above special error.

Comment: This even works in type application `dlra' = map @_ @_ @_ @_ @_ @_ @_ @_ @_ @_ @_ @ca @cb id id id id `. but maybe I should refactor a bit